# Draw polygon with gradient color in Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

I have polygon like sector. I want to fill it with gradient color.

Is it possible to do this in Geoserver?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found some code with filling image

```
<FeatureTypeStyle>
 <Rule>
   <PolygonSymbolizer>
     <Fill>
       <GraphicFill>
         <Graphic>
           <ExternalGraphic>
             <OnlineResource
               xlink:type="simple"
               xlink:href="colorblocks.png" />
             <Format>image/png</Format>
           </ExternalGraphic>
         <Size>93</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </GraphicFill>
     </Fill>
   </PolygonSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
```

i can put here big circle which is gradient, but does it has rotation or position of image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLD does not support gradient fills. The above will just repeat the image you provided over and over like tiles in a map until the polygon is filled.
I guess if you use a large enough image it will look more or less like a gradient fill.
It is possible to add support for gradient fills by coding, but it's not going to be trivial.

Comment: would be interesting how to fill gradient by coding :) Thanks

Comment: Can you ask on geotools-devel? The answer would be very long...